# Unable to get CCEditBox events

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x

I am new to cocos2dx. I am trying to create a simple EditBox here.

Here is my Code:

**HelloWorldScene.h**

```
using namespace cocos2d;
using namespace cocos2d::extension;
using namespace std;
USING_NS_CC;
USING_NS_CC::extension;
class HelloWorld : public cocos2d::CCLayer,public CCEditBoxDelegate
{
public:
virtual bool init();  
static cocos2d::CCScene* scene();
    void menuCloseCallback(CCObject* pSender);
virtual void editBoxEditingDidBegin(CCEditBox* editBox);
    virtual void editBoxEditingDidEnd(CCEditBox* editBox);
    virtual void editBoxTextChanged(CCEditBox* editBox,const std::string &text);
    virtual void editBoxReturn(CCEditBox * editBox);
CREATE_FUNC(HelloWorld);
};
```

**HelloWorldScene.CPP**

```
USING_NS_CC;
USING_NS_CC::extension;
jobject adObject;

CCEditBox  *m_pEditName;

CCScene* HelloWorld::scene() {
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object
    CCScene *scene = CCScene::create();

    // 'layer' is an autorelease object
    HelloWorld *layer = HelloWorld::create();

    // add layer as a child to scene
    scene->addChild(layer);

    // return the scene
    return scene;
}
bool HelloWorld::init() {

    /////////////////////////////
    // 1. super init first
    if (!CCLayer::init()) {
        return false;
    }

m_pEditName = CCEditBox::create(ccp(150,30),CCScale9Sprite::create("edit_query_background_normal.png"));
m_pEditName->setPosition(ccp(origin.x+visibleSize.width/2, origin.y+visibleSize.height*3/4));
m_pEditName->setFontColor(ccRED);
m_pEditName->setPlaceHolder("Zone Id:");
m_pEditName->setMaxLength(25);
m_pEditName->setReturnType(kKeyboardReturnTypeDone);
m_pEditName->setInputMode(kEditBoxInputModeAny);
m_pEditName->setDelegate(this);
addChild(m_pEditName);    
    return true;
}

void HelloWorld::editBoxEditingDidEnd(CCEditBox *editBox) { 
    __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "Log", "editBoxEditingDidEnd");
}

void HelloWorld::editBoxTextChanged(CCEditBox *editBox, const std::string &text) {
    __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "Log", "editBoxTextChanged");
//  m_pEditName->editBox.getText();
}

void HelloWorld::editBoxReturn(CCEditBox *editBox) {
    __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "Log", "editBoxReturn");
}
void HelloWorld::editBoxEditingDidBegin(CCEditBox *editBox) {

    __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "Log", "editBoxEditingDidBegin");

}
```

When I run using eclipse, I can see the EditBox is created successfully.
After click on EditBox I am able to enter data inside EditBox and also receive the event for ***`editBoxEditingDidBegin`*** method. But I am not able to get any other event after that. 
My question is why I am not able to get other events like *`editBoxTextChanged,editBoxEditingDidEnd,editBoxReturn`*.

Kindly help me to solve this issue. Any help will be definitely appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am also looking for this since a few days..